# How does the 'as' operator work in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

Take this piece of code as an example

```
foreach($xml as $node)
{
    foreach($node as $nodename=> $nodeval)
    {
        echo $nodename;
    }
}
```

$xml is a piece of xml $xml=simplexml_load_file(file.xml);

```
<customer>

<customertags>........
</customer>
```

For the variable `$node` it only contains 1 item so the loop only loops once which is a waste. How do I assign the variable `$nodename` without the need for the `foreach` loop? How exactly does the as operator create the variable `$nodename` and `$nodeval` from `$node`?

Comment: It's impossible to give advice on how to loop through a data structure you know nothing about. Please edit the question and provide some basic info.

Comment: Why should a loop looping only once be a waste?

Comment: `$node->customertags;` or `$xml->customer` ? Are you using simpleXml?

Comment: @Onheiron its a waste because if its possible to assign the result of this loop to a variable without the loop then there is no need for it.

Comment: @DanHastings, what's the result of `print_r($xml);` or `print_r($node);`?

Comment: @DanHastings, forget about it... you are wasting time on minor performance issues.

Comment: @Rolando Isidoro its an array with the element name => value

Comment: Try getting rid of the 2nd foreach and just use go straight to the assignment $node => $nodeval then you can echo $node

Comment: `as` is not an operator, it's part of the syntax of the `foreach` statement.

Comment: @deceze so what does it do? if for example i just wanted the first result of the foreach how would i get that without needing a foreach? like if i want value 4 from an array i dont need a foreach loop i can just say i want element 4 from this array

Comment: @DanHastings for 4th element why not try $arr[3] //assuming indexing starts from 0 ??

Comment: You problem is not foreach related is more about arrays. So you basically want the key from `$node` is that it?

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro kinda. i want to know how to get $xml as $node without a loop. if that loop returns 5 values then i want the first. when the foreach loop makes it first loop how does it create $node? can i do this without a loop?

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php. After that you will know exactly how everything works. That's what the docs are for.

Comment: jees guys i had a simple question and not 1 of ye read it. why does everyone gotta be so angry around here

Comment: `foreach` works on the `Iterator` interface of objects. That interface defines a few functions that `foreach` requires to iterate over it. Please investigate this interface, as some form of it is implemented by SimpleXML objects, which you can probably use to replicate what `foreach` does. I'm not interested enough in the topic at the moment to investigate this further for you. :) Hope that helps.